# Date in Text format- Birt

Tags: sql, db2, birt

I need to display a text date like " August, 2018" if it is coming like "08-02-2018".

So, I have written this 
" MONTHNAME(MAIL_DATE + 12 DAYS)||', '||YEAR(MAIL_DATE + 12 DAYS) as DateInText " wherein MAIL_DATE is today's date.

And, I have mapped in Birt like row["DateInText "], but I am not getting the value as expected like "August, 2018" .

Comment: FYI: JavaScript is also being supported in birt

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Your syntax seems to be SQL. So it's depending on the DB system you are using. Furthermore, is your MAIL_DATE a DATE or TIMESTAMP column or VARCHAR or ...? You should always test your SQL statements outside of BIRT.

Comment: Yes, MAIL_DATE is a DATE and yes, its more of a sql question to be placed in Birt.

Comment: Personally, I would do all the computation and conversion within SQL and select the formatted date as a VARCHAR2 column (in Oracle-speech: use TO_CHAR)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of in built BIRT functions to achieve this.
In the detail row of the table, right click on the cell and go to "Edit Value/Expression.."
In the expression you can try this :

```
BirtDateTime.month(new Date(dataSetRow["DateInText"]),2) + ", " + BirtDateTime.year(new Date(dataSetRow["DateInText"]));
```

I hope this works.

Thank You